# How to change "ifthenelse" conditional to "ifnum"

Tags: conditionals

I'm trying to put a conditional inside `\cfoot` from the `fancyhdr` package like this:

- if the document contains a one-page there will be no footer.
- if there are more pages the footer takes the format " \thepage of number of pages".

To set the number of pages i have used the `lastpage` package which provide the label `LastPage` allowing the user to refer to the last page of a document via `\pageref{LastPage}`.

When using `\ifthenelse` there is no problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\cfoot{\ifthenelse{\pageref{LastPage}>1}
{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

But with the use of `\ifnum` produces an error:

> !Missing = inserted
>   for \ifnum

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\newcommand{\foo}{\pageref{LastPage}}

\cfoot{\ifnum\foo>1 Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}\fi}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Where is the problem , with `\ifnum`  and how to solve it ?

Comment: I believe this has already been asked; anyway, you have to use `\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}` (with `\usepackage{refcount}`) and not `\pageref{LastPage}`. With `\ifthenelse` it should work the same.